# Python - Lista alternando los números

Tags: python, bucles, pair

Necesito ayuda para este ejercicio que no soy capaz de resolver. Solicitamos al usuario un número y hay que imprimir una lista alternando primero los números pares y luego los impares. Por ejemplo:

"Please type in a number: 6.

2

1

4

3

6

5"

"Please type in a number: 5.

2

1

4

3

5"

La entrada es el total de números que alcanzará la lista, y deben imprimirse alternando primero los números pares y luego los impares

Mi código:

```
number = int(input("Please type in a number:"))

for i in range(1,number + 1):
    for j in range(1, number + 1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(i)
        else:
            print(j)
```

Muchas gracias a todos,

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: No está claro cómo es la entrada y cual debe ser la salida. ¿La entrada es `6 2 1 4 3 6 5`, introducidos por el usuario y separados por espacio? y ¿la salida debe ser: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]` o `[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, o `[6, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5]` u otro formato que no he entendido?

Comment: Disculpa, el formato de stack ha hecho que no se entienda nada. La entrada es el número que quieres que sea el total de la lista, en el caso del ejemplo, un 6. Y la salida debe ser imprimir 2 1 4 3 6 5

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla es usando un `for` con incremento de 2 en 2. El `end=''` en el `print()` es para eliminar el salto de línea cada vez que se imprime.

```
number = int(input("Please type in a number: "))
for i in range(1, number+1, 2):
    if i%2: # Si esto es > 0 es lo mismo que true, o sea, es impar
        print(f'{i+1} {i} ', end='')
    else:
        print(f'{i} {i+1} ', end='')
```

[*] Advertencia, `number` debe ser un numero par.

EDIT. Con este algoritmo, `i` siempre será impar porque el incremento es de 2 a 2 (1, 3, 5...), por lo que se puede eliminar el `if` y da exactamente lo mismo:

```
number = int(input("Please type in a number: "))
for i in range(1, number+1, 2):
    print(f'{i+1} {i} ', end='')
```

Comment: Creo que lo que pretende nuestro compañero es obtener una cadena de 'number' caracteres, cuyo primera cifra sea un 2, y la siguiente un 1, y vaya aumentando siguiendo la secuencia 'par,impar,par,impar' de forma creciente continua.

Answer (score 0):

La lógica de tu código no es la correcta, porque lo único que haces es imprimir el valor de `'i'` o `'j'` durante la ejecución del loop. Para conseguir lo que quieres, necesitas añadir el resultado del cálculo a una cadena que irá creciendo en cada ejecución del `'for'`.

Este código te lo resuelve (aunque hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, esta es bastante clara)

```
number = int(input("Please type in a number:"))
par = 2
impar = 1
resultado = '2'
if number<1:
    resultado = '0'
for i in range(0, number-1):
    if i%2:
        resultado = resultado +' ' + str(par+2)
        par = par + 2
    else:
        resultado = resultado +' ' + str(impar)
        impar = impar + 2
    i +=i
print(resultado)
```

Esto lo que hace es recorrer el loop el número de veces que se indica en el `'input'`, y va añadiendo valores a la cadena `'resultado'`, que se imprimirá al terminar el loop, y el resultado se verá tal que así:

Si el input vale '3':

```
Please type in a number:3
2 1 4
```

Si el input vale '12':

```
Please type in a number:12
2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 10 9 12 11
```